# Number of non-linear steps in range, without iterative calculation?

Tags: nonlinear-system

I want to quickly calculate how many steps `S` there are between some `min` and `max`, where `n=min` to start with, given some particular non-linear formula, e.g. `n'=n * 1.01`, `n'' = n' * 1.01` etc. until `n` exceeds `max`.

The simplest way to determine `S` is to do so iteratively, i.e. step from `min` till we exceed `max` and count the total steps whose resultant values fell within the range.

However, does a fast analytical solution exist for this? Perhaps not only for this simple formula, but for any non-linear series? Or must we iterate to find the solution?

Comment: This all depends on if you can form an equation for the general term (non-iterative form). In your example we can take $n_0=min, n_1 = min * q, n_2 = min*q^2$ etc. and the general term is $n_k = min*q^k$. Now you set $n_k>max$ and solve for $k$. Easy peasy. But for a different scheme this could be impossible.

Comment: I'm just toying with these. Set $n_0 = 0.3$ and iterate $n_{k+1} =\tan n_k$. When does $n$ exceed 10 ? Good luck to anyone solving this ...